# Configuring dojo loader paths

Tags: dojo, requirejs, amd

I'm having trouble with setting up `dojo`. Anything defined in the `dojo` config seems to correctly load using the `localhost:8080/Scripts/foo.js` path. However if I then try to load a module without this, say:

```javascript
require(['foo'], function (_foo) { });
```

Then the client fails the request, with the attempted path being `localhost:8080/foo.js`. Obviously wrong.

What do I need to change?

```javascript
// Configuration for the dojo AMD module loader
dojoConfig = {
   baseUrl: "/Scripts",
   packages: [{
      name: 'esri',
      location: 'esri'
   }, {
      name: 'dojo',
      location: 'dojo/dojo'
   }, {
      name: 'dojox',
      location: 'dojo/dojox'
   }, {
      name: 'dijit',
      location: 'dojo/dijit'
   }, {
      name: 'jquery',
      location: '.',
      main: 'jquery-2.0.2'
   },
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either of these will solve your problem:

1. Set `dojoConfig.tlmSiblingOfDojo = false`.
2. Define 'foo' as a package with an explicit location.

Comment: Dojo documentation: "baseUrl: (string) a path to prepend to a computed path if the computed path is relative as described by the process below. If defined, the has feature config-tlmSiblingOfDojo is false; otherwise, it is true." So its already false. However I have put foo into a folder, and defined the folder as a package. This seems to work. So package "bar", with "bar/foo" loading the file.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this link : http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/dojo_config/

Maybe the change from packages to modulePaths would help you.

Otherwise i would define the packages on the ordinary way :

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.1/dojo/dojo.xd.js"></script>
```

regards